# Port 5005 on my VPS is listening, but closed

Tags: linux, port, port-forwarding

I have a program running on port 5005, and the port is listening and accessible via localhost:

```
znc-admin:~/.znc$ netstat -tulpn | grep 5005
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5005            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25476/znc    

znc-admin:~/.znc$    wget -p http://localhost:5005
--2014-11-26 11:25:21--  http://localhost:5005/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:5005... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1790 (1.7K) [text/html]
Saving to: `localhost:5005/index.html'

100%[===================================================>] 1,790       --.-K/s   in 0s

2014-11-26 11:25:21 (155 MB/s) - `localhost:5005/index.html' saved [1790/1790]

Loading robots.txt; please ignore errors.
--2014-11-26 11:25:21--  http://localhost:5005/robots.txt
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:5005... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 26 [text/plain]
Saving to: `localhost:5005/robots.txt'

100%[===================================================>] 26          --.-K/s   in 0s

2014-11-26 11:25:21 (2.87 MB/s) - `localhost:5005/robots.txt' saved [26/26]

FINISHED --2014-11-26 11:25:21--
Total wall clock time: 0.01s
Downloaded: 2 files, 1.8K in 0s (88.2 MB/s)
```

Unfortunately, the port appears closed from this port forwarding testing website: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

and the page `http://<my ip>:5005` times out in my browser.

It is driving me crazy, what am I missing?

Comment: Why the downvote? Do you have any suggestions for improvement, or should I just remove the question? I left the question here because I think others might benefit, but let me know what you think. Getting downvoted without any clear feedback seems confusing to me.

Comment: Alright, so what the hell **is** a network slug?  All I can find is the github page for that ZNC thing, but no documentation about what the guy meant that term to mean.

Comment: I'm still not sure, but in the context of setting up my ZNC IRC proxy server, it is the IRC network to which I am connecting. For example, I used `irc.freenode.net` as the network slug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a feeling this was simple, but perhaps this will help someone. I just needed to add an exception to my security group (ie my firewall) through my AWS console.

I have come across this exact scenario several times before, after spending an hour plus checking my server's firewall. So I hope this will be a reminder to myself and others to check other potential "firewalls"!